# Difference between #include <filename> & #include "filename"

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

Here is a preprocessor directive in **C** :

```
#include <filename>
```

we can write it in this way also:

```
#include "filename"
```

Is there any difference between these two?

Comment: Amazingly, the top linked question for this has almost exactly the same title. So this question should really not have been that hard to find elsewhere.

Comment: Yes there is. And it is very easy to find it out yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In general, the `<>` version should look only in "system directories", while the `""` should look in the "local directories" first, and then the system directories.

What that actually means is implementation dependent. In most cases `""` will look in the *current* directory first, but in some implementations it will look in the directory of the source (`.c`) file first (and some compilers have a switch for that). Also, behavior is different w.r.t. the "set of system directories" to search if "local directory search" fails (the same as for `<>` or not).